# What are the supported formats for `<amp-anim>`

Tags: amp-html

I cannot find anywhere [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-anim/amp-anim.md) what file formats are supported beside `.gif`. Are `.gifv` or `webm` include on this extension or is `<amp-video>` the intended tag for these formats and `<amp-anim>` is only meant for `.gif`?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I understand

> A runtime-managed animated image - most typically a GIF.

as

> anything that is an image, but not a video

So as long as a browser would be able to render it using an `<img>` tag and it's animated, then it probably qualifies for using `<amp-anim>`.

Comment: What you are linking to are the _extended elements_, `<amp-video>` is a core built-in element. 

For reference see [<amp-video>](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/builtins/amp-video.md).

In addition, what image format are there for animated images besides gif?